# Binding a wrapper's height to height of specific child element

Tags: javascript, css

I have a setup where a double-wrapper contains several elements of varying height. They're all arranged next to each other via `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` with one of them being considered 'active'.

```
<section class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery__content">
        <img class="gallery__item gallery__item--img" src="assets/GIRM/1.png" width="350" heigth="197">
        <img class="gallery__item gallery__item--img" src="assets/GIRM/2.png" width="1280" heigth="800">
        <img class="gallery__item gallery__item--img" src="assets/GIRM/3.png" width="1280" heigth="511">
        <img class="gallery__item gallery__item--img" src="assets/GIRM/4.png" width="1135" heigth="742">
    </div>
</section>
```

I want to limit the height of the wrapper (at either level) to the height of the active child, with `overflow: hidden` cutting off anything that's higher. Right now, I achieve this by using js to set `outerWrapper.maxHeight = activeChild.height`.

However, the children can be arbitrary elements, not just imgs and it's not unlikely that they will change their height. With the current js, I have to catch those occurances and reapply the max-height for the new value, if the height changes with a transition it gets even worse.

Is there a way to bind the height of either of the wrappers to the height of a specific child element in css, maybe by making it ignore all other elements for height-computation? If not, is there a better way to do this with js?

Comment: If all children but the active are set to `display: none`, and the container set to `height: auto` it should automatically scale to the "active"/visible child.

Comment: It would, but I still need to display the other children. (They're visible off to the site to indicate they're available, but they're not important enough that the active child should have a huge margin beneath it just to accommodate one of them)

Comment: set `position: absolute` on the non-active ones, then. (and, obviously, the proper `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` rules)

Comment: didn't think of that. I'll try it, but I have doubts that it will work well with other things going on, esp. the non-transitionable switch from relative to absolute.

Comment: well, if you absolutely position them where they would be relatively positioned, you don't have to transition them.

Comment: yeah, the transitions don't make too many problems (wasn't sure about that, just had a bad feeling and thought it might be because of them). Still, position needs to stay relative since the resizing means that they would go out of alignment with absolute. One thing I just tried and that seems to work pretty well is giving all except for the active child a `margin-bottom:-99999%`. See any problems in that approach?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/5bLj6npp/) work?

Code for the lazy:

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div id="under-wrapper">
    <img class="child" id="child1" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="150">
    <img class="child active" id="child2" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="300">
    <img class="child" id="child3" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="350">
    <img class="child" id="child4" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="200">
  </div>
  <div id="over-wrapper">
    <img class="child" name="child1" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="150">
    <img class="child active" name="child2" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="300">
    <img class="child" name="child3" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="350">
    <img class="child" name="child4" src="https://pro.buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28341" height="200">
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS** (minus the aesthetics)

```
section {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#over-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 120px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

img.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

#under-wrapper img {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#under-wrapper img:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS** (well, jQuery)

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $('img').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var child = $(this).attr('name');
  $('#'+child).addClass('active');
});
```

**How did I do it?**

1. I added a `section` wrapper with `overflow:hidden` (to cut off the extra) and `position:relative` (to contain the absolutely-positioned child elements).
2. I created two inner wrappers *with the exact same contents*, except that the latter has its `id` attributes replaced with `name`, for ease of access later on.
3. I left the first inner wrapper (`under-wrapper`) alone (it can just behave normally), but the second (`over-wrapper`) I made absolutely positioned. This is so the contents of this wrapper don't effect the height of the `section`.
4. I created a rule for the `active` class, so *while inactive images in the `under-wrapper` are `display:none`, active ones are `display:inline-block` and `visibility:hidden`.* This means only the active image will be influencing the height of the `section`, and the rest will be hidden. Meanwhile, all the upper images have to do are sit there and look nice.
5. The javascript is simple; just a click handler on the images which gives it the active class and takes away everybody else's. Clicking an upper image takes the name of it ('child1', 'child2', etc.) and selects the corresponding lower image with the matching id, and gives it the active class.

If this doesn't completely answer your question or I broke a rule, I'd be glad to change my solution. Maybe someone else can use it to find a more convenient/efficient solution that doesn't involve two sets of the same elements.

Comment: This does seem to work pretty well for the problem I described above, though it changes a bit too much to be used in my specific implementation (there's a gallery script that will want to access positioning and similar) (plus, the content-doubling is a bit icky). In the question comments we discussed different ways of making the non-active children 'not count' while still displaying them. It also has its problems, but I guess I'll go with the huge negative margin-bottom since that doesn't conflict with anything else in my case.